# Conda Verification Failed

Tags: jupyter, anaconda

I was trying to install jupyter package for anaconda in my current environment but constantly getting the following error.

> Preparing transaction: done Verifying transaction: failed
>
> CondaVerificationError: The package for ipython located at
>   D:\Anaconda\pkgs\ipython-7.1.1-py36h39e3cac_0 appears to be corrupted.
>   The path 'Lib/site-packages/IPython/lib/tests/test.wav' specified in
>   the package manifest cannot be found.
>
> CondaVerificationError: The package for notebook located at
>   D:\Anaconda\pkgs\notebook-5.7.2-py36_0 appears to be corrupted. The
>   path
>   'Lib/site-packages/notebook/static/components/MathJax/extensions/a11y/invalid_keypress.mp3'
>   specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

I have Googled many Q&A for this problem, mostly I found:

```
conda clean --packages --tarballs 
conda clean --all
```

After trying both I tried the installation again, but none worked...

Any solution for this?

Comment: It seems that problem was anyhow with conda installation.
I tried pip installation for jupyter and it worked fine.

    python -m pip install jupyter

Comment: But anytime I'm trying to perform conda install it's showing the same verification failed error.

Comment: me too,how did you solve this problem?can you install package via conda now?

Comment: `conda update conda` worked for me. Got it from [this link](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8149)

Comment: I had the same problem when I used 'conda install tensorflow'. I could solve it by uninstalling anaconda and installing it again in a different path.

Answer (score 6):

First try this:

```
conda remove {failing_packages}
conda install {failing_packages}
```

Where `{failing_packages}` is/are the package(s) for which an error is reported.

If that fails, you could try forcing an over-install (this solution is very handy and will likely fix many issues):

```
conda install -f {failing_packages}
```

So, for example, for the original poster of this question, it would be;

```
conda remove ipython notebook
conda install -f ipython notebook
```

Note that in future releases of Conda, the `-f` will be removed and you may have to use `--clobber` or `--force-reinstall` flags.

I personally like to use the `--force-reinstall` flag, and worst case scenario I will remove the failing package's directory (i.e. ~/miniconda3/pkgs/{failing_package}...) manually before using the `--force-reinstall` to re-install it. That always works really well to fix any package issue.

If all that fails, try these steps, one by one, in order, till it works:

```
conda clean --packages --tarballs
conda clean --all
conda update conda

conda activate base
conda install --revision 0
```

Please note that each command has implication as to your environment.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that problem was anyhow with conda installation.
I tried pip installation for jupyter and it worked fine.

```
python -m pip install jupyter
```

Comment: This answer doesn't actually solve the problem.

Comment: yes, this is a work around. However you can try **conda update conda** to resolve the broken package issue.